# C# when building a multiple choice quiz, how do we count the correct / wrong answers and form a score base on the counts?

Tags: c#, multiple-choice

So i am going to have 4 questions and each question is worth 25 points and full point is 100.
I am not sure how to count the answer base on my code and form score code.
Thank you for helping me out.
(I put 1 question to make the code shorter but in my VS there are 4 questions)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MCQuiz
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            string answer;

            Console.WriteLine("Q1-Every Statement in C# language must terminate with: ");
            Console.WriteLine(" \t a.  ; ");
            Console.WriteLine(" \t b.  , ");
            Console.WriteLine(" \t c. . ");
            Console.WriteLine(" \t d.  ? ");
            Console.WriteLine();


            Console.Write("Enter the letter (a, b, c, d) for correct Answer: ")

            answer = Console.ReadLine();

            if (answer == "a")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your Answer '{0}' is Correct.", answer);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your Answer '{0}' is Wrong.", answer);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("****************************************");
           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you succeed? Did we solve your problem? ....

Comment: It did ! thank you very much! I just upvoted your answer because I didn't know how to close the question. I am new here.

Comment: You can trick the checkmark next to the upvote button to mark my answer as the correct anwer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could track the totalScore in an integer variable and add 25 each correct answer using the `+=` operator, which is a shorthand for `totalScore = totalScore + 25` in the following example.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int totalScore = 0;   // initiate variable
        string answer;

        Console.WriteLine("Q1-Every Statement in C# language must terminate with: ");
        Console.WriteLine(" \t a.  ; ");
        Console.WriteLine(" \t b.  , ");
        Console.WriteLine(" \t c. . ");
        Console.WriteLine(" \t d.  ? ");
        Console.WriteLine();


        Console.Write("Enter the letter (a, b, c, d) for correct Answer: ")

        answer = Console.ReadLine();

        if (answer == "a")
        {
            totalScore += 25;   // add score
            Console.WriteLine("Your Answer '{0}' is Correct.", answer);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your Answer '{0}' is Wrong.", answer);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("****************************************");
        Console.WriteLine($"You scored {totalScore} points"); // output result
    }
}
```